# ffmpeg: вырезать(crop) несколько областей видео в отдельные файлы одновременно

Tags: ffmpeg, видео

У меня есть записи скайп-видеоконференций. Мне нужно извлечь каждую веб-камеру из записа на отдельное видео с помощью ffmpeg. Записи очень длинные, поэтому было бы очень хорошо, если бы я мог одновременно извлекать сразу все камеры за один проход

Возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804431/multiple-crop-operations-on-input-video-using-ffmpeg

Нужно просто сделать несколько фильтров и замапить их на несколько выходов, как здесь:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -filter_complex
"[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1];[0:v]crop=1024:1024:1023:0[out2]"
-map [out1] -map 0:a out1.mp4
-map [out2] -map 0:a out2.mp4
```